# Getting mouse-position relatively to a control

Tags: c#, winforms, mouse

I'm trying to find a way to get the mouse position relatively to the upper left corner of a control, is there a way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Call [`MyControl.PointToClient()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoclient.aspx) passing [`Cursor.Position`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.position.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

yourControl.[PointToClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoclient%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)(Control.MousePosition)